# Can iOS 11 beta users update to stable iOS 11 when it’s released?

Tags: iphone, downgrade, ios

I would like to know which of these two things would be required to get the stable release of [ios-11](/questions/tagged/ios-11):

- Upgrade from the iOS 11 beta to stable iOS 11
- Downgrade from the iOS 11 beta and upgrade to stable iOS 11

Answer (score 1):

When the Golden Master version of iOS 11 is publicly released, you will not need to downgrade to iOS 10. The Golden Master version will be the same thing as the publicly released iOS version, give no new bugs are found.

Source: https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Golden_Master

Answer (score 0):

When you get the Golden Master version of iOS 11, that will be the publicly released iOS 11 . You need not downgrade to iOS 10 to get iOS 11 again.